# Hahn-Banach theorem in separable space

Tags: functional-analysis, separable-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

**Let $E$ be a normed separable space with infinite dimension.**

**a) Show that there exist a sequence $(M_k)$ of finite dimension subspaces such that $M_k\subset M_{k+1}$, for all $k$, and $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}M_k$ is a dense subset of $E$.**

**b) Using Hahn-Banach Theorem, show that there exist a sequence of functions $(\varphi_k)\subset E'$ such that $\Vert \varphi_k \Vert=1$, for all $k$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\varphi_k(x)=0$ for all $x\in E$.**

For item a), let $D=\{x_k;k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ a dense subset of $E$ which exists beacuse $E$ is separable. Then $M_k=span\{x_1,...,x_k\}$ solves.

My problem is with item b), can anyone help me with ideas?

Comment: HB will provide a norm-1 functional that vanishes on $M_k$.

Comment: can you show me this result? because I just know that one wich provides a norm-1 functional f such that f(x_0)=||x_0|| for each x_0 in E.

Comment: See proposition 6.6 [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/3103_handout_6.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiw9pSN08btAhVmxFkKHV-5CqIQFjABegQIKBAB&usg=AOvVaw0HT02VGysWGBLSkYWJltwa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $k$. Choose $y\in E\setminus M_k$. On $\operatorname{span}M_k\cup\{y\}$, define a linear functional $\varphi_k$ with $\varphi_k(y)=1$, $\varphi_k(x_j)=0$, $j=1,\ldots,k$. This works because $y$ is linearly independent with $M_k$.

We need to show that $\varphi_k$ is bounded. We have
\begin{align}
\|\varphi_k\|&=\sup\{\frac{|\varphi_k(x+\lambda y)|}{\|x+\lambda y\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ x\in M_k\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\{\frac{|\lambda|}{\|x+\lambda y\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ x\in M_k\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\{\frac{1}{\|x/\lambda+ y\|}:\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\},\ x\in M_k\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\sup\{\frac{1}{\|y-x\|}:\ x\in M_k\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\inf\{\|y-x\|:\ x\in M_k\}}\\[0.3cm]
&=\frac1{\operatorname{dist}(y,M_k)}<\infty
\end{align}
Knowing that $\varphi_k$ is bounded, we can extend it by Hahn-Banach to $\varphi_k\in E'$, that satisfies $\varphi_k|_{M_k}=0$.

Now, given $x\in E$ and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $k_0$ such that $\|x-x_{k_0}\|<\varepsilon$. Then, for any $k>k_0$,
$$
|\varphi_k(x)|\leq|\varphi_k(x-x_{k_0})|+|\varphi_k(x_{k_0})|
=|\varphi_k(x-x_{k_0})|\leq\|x-x_{k_0}\|<\varepsilon. 
$$
Thus $\lim_k\varphi_k(x)=0$.